# Change Value of Custom JButton Click

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, joptionpane

I am trying to change the value of clicking a custom `JButton` in my `JOptionPane` because it defaults as -1, the same as the value of clicking the exit button in the top right. I would like to have different behaviors based on whether the `JButton` is clicked or the exit button is clicked. Here is a sample of my code. How can I do this?

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Find nth Fib");
        JTextField n = new JTextField();

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String output = n.getText();
                frame.dispose();
                //reference to external method with String output as arg
            }
        });

        panel.add(b1);
        panel.add(n);

        Object[] options = {"Quit"};

        int pos = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, panel, 
                "Enter a number", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, options, null);

        if (pos == 0 || pos == -1) { //check if quit button or X button are pressed
            frame.dispose();
            System.out.println("exit button pressed");
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Your buttons have different behaviors already. For example, if you remove `frame.dispose();` on line 21, the Button won't close the program, but the exit button at the top right will.

Answer (score 0):

> Add the button as an option (not as part of the panel):

```
Object[] options = {"Find nth Fib", "Quit"};
```